# Using special property names in Dynamic LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

I'm constructing a Dynamic LINQ query like this:

```
"Guid=Guid(\"" + entityId + "\")"
```

This is eventually passed into a `.Where()` query, somewhere in the code that I call.

I'm getting this error:

> ParseException: '.' or '(' expected

This seems to be because it doesn't find the `Guid` property, but rather the `Guid` function.

How can I query on the `Guid` property of my object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Guid` is indeed a keyword. You can escape keyword identifiers by prefixing them with `@`.

The correct expression looks like this:

```
"@Guid=Guid(\"" + entityId + "\")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to tidy up Kendall's answer I think the more elegant approach is to let Dynamic LINQ handle the type conversions by using parameterized queries.

```
myIqueryable1.Where("@Guid=@0", entityId)
```